Can we do our nikkah in this situation without both our parents knowing and consent?
Salam Alaykum, so there is this girl I want to marry and I heard that a man is allowed to marry without parents consent but I don't know if I am allowed to marry without them knowing. If I can do that then there is only one problem. The girl I want to marry is in a difficult situation, her parent don't let her pray and don't like it when she does things for Allah so her parents get angry, but the father doesnt care about anything whatever she does haram or good and even if her mom doesn't allow her to pray and that. Her parents would lead her to the wrong path, and I guided her and she became a better muslim, her mother didn't let her wear hijab and now she wears a niqab Allahumma baarik. If I marry her we will both be doing everything for Allah and do more good deeds, so I see that its better if she marries me. If she tells her parents she wants to marry me, her parents may send her back to her country and may do an arranged marriage for her as her parents don't allow her to marry anyone other than where they are from. Also we both are in different countries, I want to do nikkah online and she will still be living with her parents until after a few years I'll take her if I marry her by nikkah. We both really want to be halal together so please help me and tell me if our nikkah will be valid like this when we do it online and when she is far and when the situation is like this. If I do nikkah with her right now, she will still be living with her parents until I come to get her after a few years, depending when Allah will allow me and has planned for me. Also I know how she looks like and she doesn't know how I look like, so do I have to show her my face to do nikah with her? Please help me and Thank you!
